# Firebase "Email link sign in" using "Custom domain" is not working. (for Flutter passwordless authentication)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, custom-domain, password-less

**Issue:** When tapping on redirect link it gives `Page Not Found`.[image]

**What is expected:** Tapping on the redirect link sent to your email should open up the app if it is installed.

Have tried the suggestions from most related solutions on StackOverflow and GitHub.

My custom domain in Hosting:[image]

It is also authurized:[image]

Dynamic links I made:[image]

ActionCodeSettings URL prod project: `https://myprodapp.com/login/welcome`

firebase.json:[image]

added to info.plist:[image]

Associated domain for iOS[image]

**Callback URL:**
Android[image]
iOS[image]

Need to mention we have two firebase projects connected to our flutter app - one for the development environment (dev) and the other for the product environment (prod). Passwordless sign in with the firebase default domain works on dev environment for only Android. So seems the coding part works fine.

Comment: It is not necessary to have multiple Firebase apps- you can use Firebase emulators to run a localised version of almost every Firebase service with extra debug tooling.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelZasas, for your suggestion. We will consider that for the later projects. But for now, I appreciate any suggestion on this email link sign issue. The reason I mentioned the dev and prod project was to say that the code is working and the issue might come from a custom domain or ... else.

Comment: Do all the other firebase services work as expected in your production environment?

Comment: @RafaelZasas yes. We are using google and apple authentication as well as some firestore, storage and cloud function services; they are all working as expected.